# Property of $ k $-degenerate graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

An undirected graph is $ k $-degenerate if every subgraph has a vertex of degree at most $ k $. I am trying to prove two properties of $ k $-degenerate graphs.

1) If the average degree of $ G $ is at most $ k $, then $ G $ is $ k $-degenerate where the average degree is the sum of all degree divided by the number of vertices. For this part, I'm thinking of using contradiction. Suppose there exists a subgraph $ H $ where $ \deg{(u)} \geq k + 1 $ for all $ u \in H $. What I see from this is that the number of edges is very large compared to the number of vertices in $ H $, so the average degree of $ H $ is large. I want to conclude then that the average degree of $ G $ must exceed $ k $ even if $ G - H $ is sparse, but couldn't see a way to do so.

2) If $ G $ is $ k $-degenerate, then $ G $ contains an independent set of size at least $ |V(G)| / k $. An independent set is a set of vertices that are pairwise non-adjacent. I'm not sure how to proceed with this.

Comment: Did somebody tell you those statements are true, or are these "prove or disprove" problems? Because they sound fishy to me.

Comment: 1) Isn't a subgraph of a $k$-degenerate graph always $k$-degenerate? Well, what if you start with any old grapg $H$, and then get a bigger graph $G$ by adding zillions of isolated vertices, bringing the average degree of $G$ down nearly to $0$? So according to 1), $G$ should be $k$-degenerate? Which means that $H$, as a subgraph of $G$, is also $k$-degenerate? But $H$ was any old graph.

Comment: 2) Isn't the complete graph $K_6$ $5$-degenerate?  Does it have an independent set of size $\ge\frac65$ ?